# How to draw a dashed line across a rectangle in PixiJS and Angular?

Tags: angular, pixi.js

[image: Shape]

The following snippet draws a filled, solid-stroked rectangle in its own PixiJS application. `PIXI.Graphics` provides no built-in way to draw dashed strokes.

```js
import {
    Component,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Autodetect, create and append the renderer to the body element
        let renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 400, {
            backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
            antialias: true
        });
        document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(renderer.view);
        // Create the main stage for your display objects
        let stage = new PIXI.Container();
        // Initialize the pixi Graphics class
        let graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
        // Set the fill color
        graphics.beginFill(0x222222); // Red
        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xff0000);
        // Draw a circle
        graphics.drawRoundedRect(240, 150, 100, 100, 10); // drawCircle(x, y, radius)
        // Applies fill to lines and shapes since the last call to beginFill.
        graphics.endFill();
        // Append child to Stage
        stage.addChild(graphics);
        // Rendering 
        renderer.render(stage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is just use dashed lines. I answered https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/1333 as well.

```js
PIXI.Graphics.prototype.drawDashLine = function(toX, toY, dash = 16, gap = 8) {
  const lastPosition = this.currentPath.shape.points;

  const currentPosition = {
    x: lastPosition[lastPosition.length - 2] || 0,
    y: lastPosition[lastPosition.length - 1] || 0
  };

  const absValues = {
    toX: Math.abs(toX),
    toY: Math.abs(toY)
  };

  for (
    ;
    Math.abs(currentPosition.x) < absValues.toX ||
    Math.abs(currentPosition.y) < absValues.toY;
  ) {
    currentPosition.x =
      Math.abs(currentPosition.x + dash) < absValues.toX
        ? currentPosition.x + dash
        : toX;
    currentPosition.y =
      Math.abs(currentPosition.y + dash) < absValues.toY
        ? currentPosition.y + dash
        : toY;

    this.lineTo(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y);

    currentPosition.x =
      Math.abs(currentPosition.x + gap) < absValues.toX
        ? currentPosition.x + gap
        : toX;
    currentPosition.y =
      Math.abs(currentPosition.y + gap) < absValues.toY
        ? currentPosition.y + gap
        : toY;

    this.moveTo(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y);
  }
};

const app = new PIXI.Application();
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const line = new PIXI.Graphics();
line.lineStyle(1, 0xffffff); 
line.moveTo(0,0);
line.drawDashLine(200, 200, 10, 3);

line.moveTo(150,0);
line.drawDashLine(150, 100, 20, 10);

line.moveTo(300,20);
line.drawDashLine(600, 20, 1, 3);

app.stage.addChild(line);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.7.1/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to move any code that tries to manipulate the html to the `ngAfterViewInit` method.

Also, you can get the reference to any element in your html template by using the `@ViewChild` decorator. That way you do not have to use `document.getElementById('demo')`.

```
import {
  Component,
  AfterViewInit,
  ElementRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div #demo></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('demo') el: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 400, {
      backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
      antialias: true
    });

    this.demo.nativeElement.appendChild(renderer.view);
    // ... rest of the code 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look at https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/1333 ?
Here is polygon code.

```
PIXI.Graphics.prototype.drawDashedPolygon = function(polygons, x, y, rotation, dash, gap, offsetPercentage){
        var i;
        var p1;
        var p2;
        var dashLeft = 0;
        var gapLeft = 0;
        if(offsetPercentage>0){
            var progressOffset = (dash+gap)*offsetPercentage;
            if(progressOffset < dash) dashLeft = dash-progressOffset;
            else gapLeft = gap-(progressOffset-dash);
        }
        var rotatedPolygons = [];
        for(i = 0; i<polygons.length; i++){
            var p = {x:polygons[i].x, y:polygons[i].y};
            var cosAngle = Math.cos(rotation);
            var sinAngle = Math.sin(rotation);
            var dx = p.x;
            var dy = p.y;
            p.x = (dx*cosAngle-dy*sinAngle);
            p.y = (dx*sinAngle+dy*cosAngle);
            rotatedPolygons.push(p);
        }
        for(i = 0; i<rotatedPolygons.length; i++){
            p1 = rotatedPolygons[i];
            if(i == rotatedPolygons.length-1) p2 = rotatedPolygons[0];
            else p2 = rotatedPolygons[i+1];
            var dx = p2.x-p1.x;
            var dy = p2.y-p1.y;
            var len = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
            var normal = {x:dx/len, y:dy/len};
            var progressOnLine = 0;
            this.moveTo(x+p1.x+gapLeft*normal.x, y+p1.y+gapLeft*normal.y);
            while(progressOnLine<=len){
        progressOnLine+=gapLeft;
                if(dashLeft > 0) progressOnLine += dashLeft;
                else progressOnLine+= dash;
                if(progressOnLine>len){
                    dashLeft = progressOnLine-len;
                    progressOnLine = len;
                }else{
                    dashLeft = 0;
                }
                this.lineTo(x+p1.x+progressOnLine*normal.x, y+p1.y+progressOnLine*normal.y);
                progressOnLine+= gap;
                if(progressOnLine>len && dashLeft == 0){
                    gapLeft = progressOnLine-len;
          console.log(progressOnLine, len, gap);
                }else{
                    gapLeft = 0;
                    this.moveTo(x+p1.x+progressOnLine*normal.x, y+p1.y+progressOnLine*normal.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }


// create app
var app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    antialias: true,
    backgroundColor: 0x808080
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);


var polygons = [];
polygons.push({x:-50, y:-50});
polygons.push({x:-50, y:50});
polygons.push({x:50, y:50});
polygons.push({x:75, y:0});
polygons.push({x:50, y:-50});


var body = new PIXI.Graphics();
body.x = 200;
body.y = 100;
app.stage.addChild(body);

function animate(time) {
    body.rotation += 0.005;
    body.clear();
    body.lineStyle(1, 0x00FF00, 0.7);
    var offsetInterval = 750;
    body.drawDashedPolygon(polygons, 0, 0, 0, 10, 5, (Date.now()%offsetInterval+1)/offsetInterval);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```